# prototype function not defined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

The following code runs fine:

```
function Button(tagName) {
  var button;
  if (tagName) button = document.createElement(tagName);
  else button = document.createElement(div);

  button.innerHTML = 'Track Order';
  button.applyJsonProperties = function(jsonProperties){
    if(jsonProperties){
      for(var cssAttribute in jsonProperties){
        this.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];
      }
    }
  }
  return button;
}
```

The following code produces an error

```
function Button(tagName) {
  var button;
  if (tagName) button = document.createElement(tagName);
  else button = document.createElement(div);

  button.innerHTML = 'Track Order';

  return button;
}
Button.prototype.applyJsonProperties = function(jsonProperties){
   if(jsonProperties){
     for(var cssAttribute in jsonProperties){
       this.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];
     }
   }
}

var divButton = new Button('div');
var props = { "color" : "blue" }
divButton.applyJsonProperties(props); //returns undefined function
```

Comment: `divButton.applyjSonProperties(props)` wrong method name

Comment: The object returned from the *Button* function when called as a constructor is not an instance of *Button*, i.e. it doesn't inherit from *Button.prototype* because it returns a DOM Button element, not the constructor's *this*.

Comment: You're missing quotes around `div` here: `document.createElement(div)`. You could simplify the code to be `tagName = tagName || 'div';` on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return button in `Button` function.

And your `applyjSonProperties` returns nothing.

Try something like this:

```js
function Button(tagName) {

  if (tagName) this.button = document.createElement(tagName);
  else this.button = document.createElement(div);

  this.button.innerHTML = 'Track Order';

}
Button.prototype.applyJsonProperties = function(jsonProperties){
  if(jsonProperties){
    for(var cssAttribute in jsonProperties){
      this.button.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];
    }
  }
  return this; //return modified (or not) instance
}

var divButton = new Button('div');
console.log(divButton.button);

var props = { "color" : "blue" }
divButton.applyJsonProperties(props);
console.log(divButton.button);
```

Comment: @RobG I updated answer. As you can see - `divButton` now is instance of custom `Button` "class" with `.button` property

Comment: is it possible to not have a `.button` property and set `this = document.createElement(tagName)` inside `function Button(tagName)`?

Comment: @guest, no, because `this` is reference to instance with his members, methods etc.. otherwise result of `new Button();` will not be just created "DOM element" instead instance of `Button`. But you can `return this.button` in method (e.g. applyJsonProperties), and result of that method will be immediately "DOM element" instead instance of `Button`. (sorry for my English =)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. As you are explicitly returning a local variable button from the constructor function, the `divButton = new Button('div')` will be a div element like `<div>Track Order</div>`. This element obviously don't have acces to `applyJsonProperties` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `this.button = button;` and reference it in `applyJsonProperties` as `this.button.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];` and remove `return button` :

```
function Button(tagName) {
  var button;
  if (tagName) button = document.createElement(tagName);
  else button = document.createElement('div');

  button.innerHTML = 'Track Order';
  this.button = button;
}
Button.prototype.applyJsonProperties = function(jsonProperties){
   if(jsonProperties){
     for(var cssAttribute in jsonProperties){
       this.button.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];
     }
   }
}

var divButton = new Button('div');
var props = { "color" : "blue" }
divButton.applyJsonProperties(props);
```

Comment: Why should he try this? A good answer should explain what was wrong in the original code, and how the solution fixes it.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but there are only few line of codes and if you understand the question property you'll notice. Anyway, you can see in this answer, I have added `this.button = button;` and reference it in `applyJsonProperties` as `this.button.style[cssAttribute] = jsonProperties[cssAttribute];`

Comment: Put that explanation in the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is called as a constructor, its *this* is initialised as a new Object that inherits from the constructor's prototype, i.e. the object's internal `[[Prototype]]` references the constructor's public *prototype* property.

When you return a different object (in the OP, a DOM HTMLButtonElement), then that object doesn't inherit from the constructor. e.g.

```js
function Button(tagName) {
  var button = document.createElement(tagName || 'button');
  return button;
}

Button.prototype.applyJsonProperties = function(jsonProperties){};

var button = new Button();

console.log('button instanceof Button?: ' + (button instanceof Button)); // false
console.log('button.constructor: ' + button.constructor); // Not Button
console.log('Typeof button: ' + typeof button); // object
console.log('Typeof button.applyJsonProperties: ' + typeof button.applyJsonProperties); // undefined
```

As Rudolf Manusadzhyan suggests, you can have the element as a property of the instance and call methods on that, e.g.

```js
function Button(tagName) {
  this.button = document.createElement(tagName || 'button');
}

Button.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.button.style.display = 'none';
}

Button.prototype.show = function() {
  this.button.style.display = '';
}

window.onload = function() {
  var button = new Button();
  button.button.textContent = 'The button';
  document.body.appendChild(button.button);
  document.getElementById('hideButton').onclick = function(){button.hide()};
  document.getElementById('showButton').onclick = function(){button.show()};
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hideButton" value="Hide the button">
<input type="button" id="showButton" value="Show the button">
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful!

Comment: How do you make sure that `var button` is an instance of `Button` in this case?